# no result from heat map WGCNA

Tags: r, hpc

I have created a heat map using WGCNA using R. But the heat map command is not showing the plot and there is no error. I have a large number of modules and traits. I am not sure if that is the reason. But I tried making it in HPC R and it still is not showing any result plot. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Jessica you could post the code you have used, however the answers below do appear to have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The plot is probably being drawn to a device that you cannot view on a cluster. If you're using the `plotNetworkHeatmap` function, say, try something like this:

```
png("plot.png", ...) #specify height, width, etc
plotNetworkHeatmap(....) #call your function
dev.off()
```

Now, `scp` the `plot.png` file over to your local machine to view the plot.

Answer (score 1):

If you've copied over from some of the WGNCA tutorials you might have additionally copied the sizeGrWindow command - it's caused some of my plots to disappear.

ie:

```
sizeGrWindow(9,6)  # delete this line
plot(...)
```